# Android: Saving ListView data when app closes

Tags: android

I have an Android app which has a list view which is updated during the lifetime of the app.

I have a 'Quit' menu option which saves the list data in a thread and then finishes the app by calling finish();

How should I save the data if the app gets killed  by the system?  In particular, when should I save the data, in onStop, onDestroy or elsewhere?

NiMuSi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save your application data in the Activity's **onPause** event. This event will be fired whether the user clicks the back button or brings some other Activity to the top (such as following a notification).

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should never save the data itself. You save the state of the listview, eg the filter value, the scroll position.

Your data might change while your app doesn't have the focus. Think like someone else just adds new data in other app, when you come back you should requery the data always.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused, perhaps I haven't explained my problem properly.

The data for the list is held in an XML file, which I need to update when the app is killed. I can do it when the user selects 'Quit' from the menu, but the app can also close in other circumstances.